# How to update ag-grid from version 18.1.0 to 20.1.0 in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "trackerui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --bh /trackerui/",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.1.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.26.4",
    "angular-tree-component": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "file-saver": "1.3.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "npm": "^6.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "to": "^0.2.9",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "xlsx": "0.12.13",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

I am getting the following errors while running the application using `ng serve`

> - ERROR in node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.d.ts(133,52):
>     error TS1005: ',' expected.
> - node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.d.ts(133,73):
>     error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
> - node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.d.ts(133,101):
>     error TS1005: ';' expected.
> - node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/gridOptionsWrapper.d.ts(133,103):
>     error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or
>     property was expected.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling ag-grid?

Comment: you also need to update your ag-grid package check answer for details

Comment: @Arikael have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ,but still getting the same error

Comment: you need to update your package with ag-grid-angular. for more information please check the answer. if it solves your problem do accept the answer so that others will get benefit out of it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you also need to upgrade `"ag-grid": "^18.1.2",` to `"ag-grid-angular": "^20.1.0",` to do so you need to following changes

**Step1:**  go to package.json and modify `"ag-grid": "^18.1.2",` to `"ag-grid-angular": "20.1.0",`

**Step2:** change your typescript version `"typescript": "~2.7.2"` to `"typescript": "~3.2.4"`

**Step3:** Run `npm update` in your project.

**Step4:** now run `ng serve`

**[Here is Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=package.json)**

Hope this will help!

Comment: after changing the version of ag-grid getting the error  `No matching version found for ag-grid@^20.1.0` while I am  hovering over ag-grid in package.json the latest version is  showing as 18.1.2 only.

Comment: they renamend packages.
correct is for version 20.1.0

`"ag-grid-angular": "^20.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.1.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.1.0",`

Comment: @TheParam , Thanks,  I have updated the packages but still getting the same error.

Comment: @TheParam is this an error due to typescript version.

Comment: @TheParam when downgrading to version 20.0.0 for all the packages ,the application is working fine.

Comment: yes "ag-grid-angular": "20.1.0" require typescript  typescript": "~3.2.4 version. updated the answer please check

Comment: Thanks very much, you have also changed the angular version to 7 ,so with version 6 also this should work fine as I am currently using Angular 6?